# How do I simulate collision(s) using a gesture, like a pan/drag?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I've got some simple things setup, like an SKNode which is updated property (checking with showsPhysics) during touches* events. What's happening is that the player node is simple pushing the other nodes out of the way -- not "bouncing" them.

An example might be simulating a cue ball being driven through the break. Where the user is controlling the cue ball directly.

I have some ideas, but they seem like they would be a very clumsy way to get the task done. Is it because the player node doesn't have a velocity perhaps?

Comment: Did you assign physics bodies with collisions set to all objects?

Comment: Yeah objects actually "collide", but as I said they are merely just pushed just out of range. They aren't thrown/dispersed very much. It doesn't seem to be affected by either of the physicsBody properties.

Comment: post the code how you setup and move the bodies. If you use move actions or set the node position directly this is expected behavior, you have to use applyforce/applyimpulse